# 'method' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, django, detailview

I am trying to count likes on each post and this is my model. But I am getting error on the item detail page

```
likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_posts')


    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

VIEW:

```
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name ='waqart/item_detail.html'

    
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ItemDetailView, self).get_context_data

        stuff = get_object_or_404(Item, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        total_likes = stuff.total_likes()
        context['total_likes']= total_likes
        return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call `get_context_data`. Change it to:

`context = super(ItemDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Is there a way that I can show the total likes of each item in the admin panel? Since my likes field is ManyToManyField. Appreciate in advance